# Sorting of data crawled from Instagram Media API (According to timestamp)

Tags: sorting, instagram

having some issues with my data output following a data crawl of Instagram API- (**https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN**). My data are written to a txt file in a descending order in accordance to time (i.e The latest post will always be the first entry while the last entry is the earliest post).

Is there any way I can tweak my codes such that when it writes to my txt file in an ascending order? Last entry will always be the most recent instagram post. Rationale being, I want to utilise the min_timestamp parameter of the API to remove duplicate data crawl.

New to this website, but here is my source code:

```
    json_data = urlopen(url).read()
    response = json.loads(json_data)


    file_output = "instagram_output_" + query + ".txt"
    f = open(file_output, 'a+')


    def convert_time_unix_to_human(input_time):
      return time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",time.localtime(int(input_time)))


    def write_to_txt(data):
     if 'text' in data['caption']:
      f.write(data['caption']['id'] + '|')
      f.write(data['caption']['created_time'] + '|')
      f.write(convert_time_unix_to_human(data['caption']['created_time']) + '|')
      f.write(data['caption']['from']['username'] + '|')
      f.write(data['caption']['from']['id'] + '|')
      f.write(str(data['location']['latitude']) + '|')
      f.write(str(data['location']['longitude']) + '|')
      f.write(str(data['likes']['count']) + '|')
      f.write(str(data['comments']['count']) + '|')

      text = data['caption']['text'].replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', ' ').encode('utf-8')
      f.write(text + '\n')

    def get_next_page(content):
      if 'pagination' in content:
         if 'next_url' in content['pagination']:
           return content['pagination']['next_url']
         else:
           return ''
      else:
        return ''


     count = 1
     while url != '' and count < 5000:
         next_data = urlopen(url).read()
         response = json.loads(next_data)
         for i in range(0, len(response['data'])):
           if response['data'][i]['caption'] is not None:

               if response['data'][i]['location'] is not None:
                  if 'latitude' in response['data'][i]['location'] and 'longitude' in response['data'][i]['location']:
                       write_to_txt(response['data'][i])
                       count_caption += 1

          url = get_next_page(response)
          count = count + 1

     f.close()
     print "Successfully crawled {0}".format(count_caption)
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are processing response and write to file from starting index(0) to ending index(response json array length). Instead try to process it reverse like,

```
for i in range(len(response['data']), 0):
```

Then you might get the data to be written in ascending order